# AutoMapper and implicit operator - infinite loop

Tags: c#, automapper

I have viewModel class and boClass and i want to pass the view model object to a method which accept object of boClass. Therefore, i decided to use implicit operator as you can see in the example.

```
    public class MyClassViewModel
    {

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator MyClassBO(MyClassViewModel vm)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<MyClassBO>(vm);
        }
    }

    public class MyClassBO
    {

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

    }
```

I am using AutoMapper inside the implicit operator method. it works good if i am adding `cfg.CreateMap<MyClassViewModel , MyClassBO>()` to the configuration.

if i am not doing it, automapper, for some reason, invoke the implicit operator method again and i am getting infinite loop of AutoMapper and the implicit operator method.

My questions are:

1. Why is that happen and how can i solve this? i don't want to crash the server if i forget to use CreateMap.
2. If CreateMap is the only way to solve the problem, is there an option to add CreateMap only for class combination that not exists in my AutoMapper configuration file?

Comment: Looks like AutoMapper will look for implicit casts before attempting to do it's magic with reflection.  So, either don't use AutoMapper in the implicit operator or just use AutoMapper instead of a implicit cast.

Comment: Why stick to bad design and have to find hacky workarounds for it?